# Wyse/Thinos Deployment Questions

Tags: dell, citrix

New to Thinos environment, I have managed to install WDM with IIS ftp deploy a Citrix ICA connection using `WNOS.ini` config file. This has left me with a few questions about my deployment.

1. I have added the syntax code `AutoSignOff=yes` which is working great however when the user locks their Citrix session it is not locking their wyse profile. allowing anonymous user start a new citrix session.
2. We are a PCI compliance company and little worried about using FTP deploy config files to wyse. Can we integrate SFTP? Any security risk using FTP deploy the config file give we deploying admin password in here.
3. Can we limit the citrix application presented to user? E.G. only show Citrix desktop application.
4. How can I update my Thinos framework? How do I find the correct model/framework of my Wyse device.

Information about Wyse terminals I have:

```
MODEL NO. Tx0D
PART NO. 909641-03l
```

Thank you in advance for all you help!